# OutOfBoundsException on .charAt(), looking for explanation

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public  static void getImage() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    String element = input.nextLine( );//

    // tokenize string with " " as the delimiter
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer( element, " " );

    // store y and x variables
    imageHeight = Integer.parseInt( tokenizer.nextToken( ) );
    imageWidth = Integer.parseInt( tokenizer.nextToken( ) );
    System.out.println(imageHeight);
    System.out.println(imageWidth);

    buffer = new char[100] [100];
    System.out.println( "Getting Image ..." ); 


for ( int i = 0; i < imageHeight; i++ ) 
{ 

    element = input.nextLine();
    for ( int j = 0; j < imageWidth; j++ ) 
    {

    buffer[i][j] = element.charAt(j);

    }

}

    input.close( );

}
```

the whole code compiles but above is the portion of the whole code that is giving me the error when i run it. The objective of the code is to create a multidimensional array that when printed it displays an image made up of characters in a text file. It obtains the indexes by parsing the specified .txt file. The first 2 read tokens are numbers that define the size of the array. Then it continues to read the .txt file and assign the characters to the array at the locations they are at in the original text file, eventually creating an image made up of characters.

this part of the code is supposed to place all of the characters in the file into the array, but im getting running errors. Please Help!

Comment: Your base assumption is that `element` has the same length as `imageWidth` - add debug printing to test if this assumption is true ;)

Comment: This can happen when imageWidth is more the element charaters can you show the code for caculating imageWidth

Comment: i added the code preceding. The way it obtains the size of imageWidth is by reading the the 2nd number in the .txt file that is specified before by the user.

Comment: I figured out my error. It wasn't in the coding it was in the .txt file i had, the file had 1 empty character at the last point in the array when it should have been a space. Thank you all though! Your suggestions are what influenced me checking the file!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get char at empty location.Add some validation before accessing particular location(j).

element.lenght () > 0